# Targetting a Range With Dynamic Row Reference Based On Search

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm real new to VBA coding and have been doing alright but I have now hit a wall with my final (and probably more complex than it needs to be) macro of the worksheet. I've been trying to make it work all weekend through multiple google searches and using various answers from stackoverflow's other questions to compile my own script, but to no avail. This is what I have so far (apologies coders, I know this will look like it was written by a 3 year-old):

```
Sub Build_Delete()
Dim rngA As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rngA = Worksheets("Database").Range("D9:D177").End(xlUp)
For Each cell In rngA
If cell.Value = Range("A2").Value Then
cell.Select
Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row & ":AB" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
Selection.Delete
End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

The above works, no errors are returned, however it doesn't do anything noticeable.

I'm aware this is most likely atrocious, so this is what I am trying to do:

`Database!D9:D177` contains the titles for a set of data in columns D to AB (4 to 28) .

There is an ActiveX Search Box that populates cell `Database!A2` in real time with whatever is searched (eg. "Test" typed into Search Box, "Test" appears in cell Database!A2).

When I run the macro, I want it to check range `Database!D9:D177` for the text string found in `Database!A2`, then delete the contents of columns D to AB for that row (eg. A2 = "test", Found "test" in cell D21, Delete D21:AB21).

The row is a dynamic value which is what is throwing me mostly with this, but the columns are fixed.

Also, the button for the macro is located on a separate worksheet (Front Page!), but the script will run solely on the Database! page.

Only needs to work in excel, not open office.

Only other thing I can think of that is relevant is that the cells can be left blank after deletion, they do not need to be filled, and the worksheet will never need to be printed so margins aren't an issue.

Optionally I would like to add an "Are You Sure? 'Yes' 'No' Msgbox at the start of the script, but I can play with that later as I know I am pushing my luck with this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find it faster to use `FIND` rather than check the value of each cell.
If you want to find all values in case of duplicates you can go on to use `.FINDNEXT(rFound)` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

```
Public Sub Build_Delete()

    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
    Set rngA = wrkSht.Range("D9:D177")

    With rngA
        Set rFound = .Find(wrkSht.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            If MsgBox(rFound.Value & " found on row " & rFound.Row & "." & vbCr & _
                "Delete?", vbInformation + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                rFound.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You absolute pro, this has worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: I cant for the life of me find how to PM on here. Can I include you in my Special Thanks credits?

Comment: Not sure if there is a PM on here - never tried it.  You can if you want - hardly merits it though (unless it gets me some gainful employment on a ridiculous wage :p )